# jQuery get items with attribute like

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say I've got

```
<div color-opacity="0.8" color-whatever="something" color-whateverbadinga="something">content</div>
```

What I want to do is to select every item that has attribute that begins with `color-` **(attribute name, not attribute value)**

so `<div color-dsjdjkdskjsd="something">content</div>` will match too.

Is it possible without iterating throught every item and checking every attribute?

Comment: Why don't you use `data-*` attributes?

Comment: Soo uneffective... why can't you edit your html, is it a plugin?

Comment: Probably the fastest method is to make a good regex and run it against whole HTML, because traveling through whole tree and checking everyone element and all of it's parametes makes no sence.

Comment: I dont get why you downvote it. But basing on comments I've decided to add attribute color and then color-something so I can find by color attribute and then check other attrs.

Comment: Sorry but I've done nothing else than comment, blame others.

Comment: There was nothing amazing to do tho.

Comment: @Kluska000 please see my answer below. This should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery selectors doesn't work with filtering the attribute names, you should read the attribute's name yourself, here is how you can filter the elements using `.filter()` method and  `attributes` property. **However, I don't recommend it** as it is very inefficient and generally a bad practice. Adding a class name to the elements that have such attributes and using class selector makes more sense:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   var a = this.attributes;
   for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
     if (a[i].nodeName.indexOf('color') === 0)
         return true;
   }
   return false;  
});
```

Comment: Please make your last sentence red and bold ;)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way to get what you want directly from JQuery.

The easiest solution to the root problem is to add a class ("hasColor") on all elements when you add the color attribute. This is of course assuming that you are generating the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I dont recommend creating your own attributes. However, You could do this with data attribute:

```
  <div data-coloropacity="0.8" data-colorwhatever="something" 
  data-colorwhateverbadinga="something">content</div>
```

Then create your own jquery data2 selector:

```
 jQuery.expr.pseudos.data2= $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  var regexp = new RegExp(arg);
   return function(elem) {
    for(var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++) {
        var attr = elem.attributes[i];
        if(regexp.test(attr.name)) {
            return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
   };
 });
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
 console.log($(":data2('color')").html());
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AlaZoMib/1/edit)**